# installing ruby gem hangs on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems

On a WindowsServer 2012 machine, I am trying to do:

```
gem install github_changelog_generator --verbose
```

(I've also tried adding "--platform=ruby".)  After it compiles several c files (which I see in both the output and in task manager), it hangs on the command:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe -rubygems C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake RUBYARCHDIR=C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.2.0/github_changelog_generator-1.11.4 RUBYLIBDIR=C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.2.0/github_changelog_generator-1.11.4
```

Sadly, if I look at task manager, ruby.exe is taking zero CPU.  I've waited for about an hour with no further results.  I've installed DevKit and successfully done a gem install of json (just as an experiment).

Thoughts of where I should go from here?

Comment: Set up a Ubuntu vm on your Windows host. Ruby doesn't go well with Windows.

Answer (score 0):

"Building native extensions" means you'll have to depend on system libraries to build parts of your gem. Unfortunately, Windows is not the best building environment for Ruby extensions and sometimes it just hangs like in this case.

The best suggestion is doing what @Rubysmith said. Set up a virtual machine with some Linux distribution and use it to your Ruby development. Ubuntu is fine, Fedora Core 22 or 23 is also very good. Debian is also an option. The flavor does not matter. Just don't waste precious time trying to adjust Windows to Ruby development.